# Can the noun "seller" (as in item/product that sells well) be used for restaurant dishes as well?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, nouns

Could I say for example "This restaurant roastbeef is a real seller, so you should try it"?
Or is the word "seller" only used for non-edible items?

Comment: I see no reason why the word cannot be used in that context.  I would avoid saying that your prime filet mignon is a "hot dish", however (at least in the Upper Midwest).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it sounds natural to call it a "real seller," but you could definitely still use seller in contexts like "best seller." I don't think there's any particular reason that "seller" couldn't be used for food items.